# Is there two way binding between table.defaultview and listview.itemsource?

Tags: wpf, listview, data-binding

I have a stackpanel with multiple usercontrols being created in code behind. When I genereate these usercontrols there are tables being filled with data in the app, then I click a button and in the code behind I want to fetch the data filled in the tables, but when I step through the code it doesn't seem like the tables are being refreshed/updated/filled with the new data. Do I need to set something to two way binding or updating something?
Here is my code.

```
private void TestGridValues_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        StackPanel stackPanel = this.TestGrids;

        foreach (UserControl child in stackPanel.Children)
        {

            Grid content = child.Content as Grid;
            ListView view = content.Children[0] as ListView;
            ItemCollection itemCollection = view.Items;
            DataRowView dataRowView = itemCollection.CurrentItem as DataRowView;
            DataTable dataTable = dataRowView.DataView.Table;

        }
    }

private void MakeGridviewColumns(DataTable table)
    {
        this.ModelerListView.ItemsSource = table.DefaultView;

        GridView gv = new GridView();
        this.ModelerListView.View = gv;

        // add the date column to gridview
        GridViewColumn dateColumn = new GridViewColumn();
        dateColumn.Header = "Date";
        gv.Columns.Add(dateColumn);
        dateColumn.DisplayMemberBinding = new Binding("Date");

        foreach (DataColumn dataColumn in table.Columns)
        {
            if (dataColumn.ColumnName == "Date")
                continue;

            GridViewColumn gvc = new GridViewColumn();
            gvc.Header = dataColumn.ColumnName;
            DataTemplate dt = new DataTemplate();
            FrameworkElementFactory txtBoxElement = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(TextBox));
            Binding bind = new Binding();
            bind.Path = new PropertyPath("Text");
            bind.Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay;
            txtBoxElement.SetBinding(TextBox.TextProperty, bind);
            txtBoxElement.SetValue(TextBox.TextProperty, "test");

            dt.VisualTree = txtBoxElement;
            gvc.CellTemplate = dt;

            gv.Columns.Add(gvc);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Don't create or manipulate UI elements in procedural code in WPF. That's what XAML is for. Create a proper ViewModel and use an `ItemsControl` instead.

Comment: can this be done if the number of columns and their headers are determined by multiple lists being generated at runtime?

Comment: I'd rather use a `DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="True"` for that, but I'm referring to the StackPanel issue not the ListView.